# Is a normalized MYSQL DB faster than one organized with comma strings?

Tags: mysql, php, normalization, denormalization

I've always used databases with comma-separated id strings, something like

```
+------+--------------+  
|  id  |    users     |
+------+--------------+
|1     |2,4,5,6,12    |
+------+--------------+
|2     |1,3,7,9       |
+------+--------------+
```

And then I used to explode the string *users* and search every number in another table.

I've always thought that it was quite insecure but I've recently heard about normalization and I suppose that the table above ought be something like this (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
+----+-----+  
| id |users|
+----+-----+
|1   |2    |
+----+-----+
|1   |4    |
+----+-----+
|1   |5    |
+----+-----+
|1   |6    |
+----+-----+
|1   |8    |
+----+-----+
|1   |12   |
+----+-----+
|2   |1    |
+----+-----+
|2   |3    |
+----+-----+
|2   |7    |
+----+-----+
|2   |9    |
+----+-----+
```

My question is, is the second one faster? and, why?

If I'm not clear enough I can exactly explain my doubts.

Comment: Normalization is pretty much the accepted best practice.  Don't fret over speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=SQL) is very poor at manipulating/analysing and extracting information from your comma type schema.

That schema is also a breach of Codd's [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules)

Rule 2: The guaranteed access rule:

> All data must be accessible. This rule is essentially a restatement of
>   the fundamental requirement for primary keys. It says that every
>   individual scalar value in the database must be logically addressable
>   by specifying the name of the containing table, the name of the
>   containing column and the primary key value of the containing row.

Just how exactly will you access the datum id = 1, users = 5 under this scenario?

You will of course need an extra field to ensure the uniqueness of every record but this will pay itself back in spades down the road. I would just remark as an aside that the field name "id" is, more or less by convention, used for PRIMARY KEYs in MySQL - it's not an obligation though.

Also, check out this [article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/08/19/ted_codd_90_relational_daddy/) in The Register for some of the rationale behind Codd's efforts to impose some sort of discipline on data modelling and storage.

The more you stick with Codd's rules and sound design principles the better. Relational algebra is the only framework out there with a sound mathematical foundation. This is unlike your Hadoops and MongoDBs which, while useful for ad-hoc niche data analysis, are not on a firm theoretical footing.

Please make the effort and take the time to have a good framework for analysing/querying your data - you'll only end up with a lot of grief (poor performance, redesigns, complex queries).

Comment: Thanks! I'll read it as soon as I can and maybe it's answered in the articles but I was doing the comma string because I thought that maybe it would be faster to only search for example values 1, 3 and 4 than look all over the database searching matches.

Comment: Indexes help a lot with that - but you can't index the comma based structure. Anyway, you've got to consider that there is more to a system than the raw speed of one particular query. System performance is an overall concept - speed and ease of design, development, implementation and maintenance. If you follow best practices, you will find your overall system will work more smoothly - believe me, I know having worked on systems that weren't properly designed!